# How to make my php project distributable like .exe file

Tags: php, xampp, wamp

I want to make my php project distributable like .exe file.

is it possible to customize wamp or xampp to inclue my project folder in that so i can ask client to install that wamp/xampp and my project will be automaticall setup on their system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using uWamp server we can bundle php project with mysql and distribute it easily. [Check this](http://www.uwamp.com/en/)

Comment: I have downloaded and installed the Uwamp. But there is no enough information of how to do bundle as a single project. Please let us know of how to do this. I am working on Wamp Server currently. I used this Uwamp server in a different sever

Answer (score 1):

Check out [phar](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.phar.php) for creating a php archive.

Comment: actually the client wants to install everything in single click so project folder then db setup and wamp installation(if not done) shd be automatically done on his system

Comment: You may need to write a windows powershell script to do the installation and copy the phar to the correct location.

Comment: thnx mkaatman for replying ,so it is possible to do this but can u please elaborate what u said coz i know only php not about windows powershell script or any example/tutorial/demo

Comment: Hi praful,I have same requirment how you have acheived this functionality please help

Comment: Sorry for late reply, Install swamp server and place your code in "WWW" folder and replace .db file with yours.